# ASP.Net - RepeaterTemplates and Events

Tags: asp.net, events, templates, drop-down-menu, repeater

Just a random question,

In ASP.Net,  I have a class that implements ITemplate. That class has a DropDownList inside of it. I want to process the SelectedIndex_Changed event of the DropDownList.

Where do I put the event processing? Is it at the page level? Is it at the template level?

Comment: Can you show the template's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the drop down exists in the template, and not at the page level, then you should handle the event in the template.  Adding some code might help clarify your question.